# Continuous choice of isotopies between hyperbolic metrics on the pair of pants

Tags: reference-request

Fix a pair of pants in the plane (i.e. a closed disk minus two smaller open disks).  Name the boundary components $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ and $\alpha_3$ and fix three positive lengths $\ell_1,\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$.

Let $M$ be the set of smooth Riemannian metrics on the pair of pants which are hyperbolic and such that all three boundary components are geodesics with lengths $\ell_1,\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$ respectively ($M$ is endowed with the $C^\infty$ topology).

There is a unique conformal metric $g_0 \in M$ and one knows that given $g \in M$ there is an isotopy from the identity $f_t, t \in [0,1]$ such that $f_t(\alpha_i) \subset \alpha_i$ for $i =1,2,3$, $f_0$ is the identity map, and the pushforward metric $f_1^*g$ is equal to $g_0$.

**My question:**  Given a continuous one parameter family of metrics $g_s \in M$ can one choose isotopies $f_{s,t}$ taking each one to $g_0$ in a continuous way?

**Edit:**  I was wrong.  Once the pair of pants is fixed there is a unique choice of $\ell_1,\ell_2$ and $\ell_3$ such that there is a conformal hyperbolic metric with boundary geodesics of those lengths.  For other values of the $\ell_i$ the solutions to the Beltrami equation in Misha's answer do not (and cannot) leave the given pair of pants invariant.

Comment: Yes, it follows from continuity of the solution of Beltrami equation. (The metric tensor $g_t$ converts to a Beltrami differential $\mu_t$.)

Comment: Doesn't that only yield that $f_{s,1}$ (the final diffeomorphism taking $g_s$ to $g_0$) is continuous?  What about the rest of the isotopy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the metric $g= Edx^2 + 2Fdxdy + Gdy^2$ defines the Beltrami differential
$$
\mu =\frac{E − G + 2iF}{E + G + 2\sqrt{EG − F^2}}
$$
For every $\mu$ one has the canonical family of Beltrami differentials
$t\mu$, $0\le t\le 1$. If $g=g_s$ depends smoothly on another parameter $s$, we also get$t\mu_s$. Solution of the corresponding Beltrami equation depends smoothly on 
the pair of parameters $(s,t)$.